# Code examples for ShieldUI components in ASP.NET Core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, shieldui

I have been asked to evaluate ShieldUI components for use in an ASP.NET Core web app that uses Razor pages. The documentation for the components I am most interested in using, the Menu, Calendar, and Grid, is devoid of any in-depth explanations and concrete examples for the component properties. For example, the sole documentation page for the Grid in ASP.NET Core contains this brief code snippet:

```
// ASP.NET Core Grid demo
@(Html.ShieldGrid()
.Name("grid")
.DataSource(ds => ds.Data(@gridData))
.SortingConfiguration(sb => sb.Multiple(true))
.PagingConfiguration(pb => pb.PageSize(12).PageLinksCount(10))
.SelectionConfiguration(sb => sb
    .Type(Shield.Mvc.UI.Grid.SelectionTypeOptions.Row)
    .Multiple(true)
    .Toggle(false))
.Columns(cb => cb.Field("id").Width(70).Title("ID"))
.Columns(cb => cb.Field("name").Title("Person Name"))
.Columns(cb => cb.Field("company").Title("Company Name"))
.Columns(cb => cb.Field("email").Title("Email Address").Width(270))
)
```

Nowhere to be found is any explanation of the ShieldGrid properties, such as the DataSource, the Data Binding configuration, or even how to use the Row and Cell editing mechanisms.

I have looked into every single one of the components listed on the 
https://www.shieldui.com/documentation page and none of the ASP.NET Core docs show anything other that a similar, brief, code snippet without any further explanation. I am also hampered by the fact that I am using the component library as a Trial user and, as such, am not entitled to even ask for help from ShieldUI directly.

I am hoping that there are developers reading this post who have some experience with using the ShieldUI components in ASP.NET Core and can point me to some concrete examples of how to use the different controls, especially how to use the controls from a Razor view page.

Comment: 1. I'm not asking anyone to do my job for me, I'm asking for help in getting past a roadblock. This, I used to think, was the driving purpose of StackOverflow. 2. I agree. 3. I'm not asking for anyone to "find this for me", but I am asking for help by anyone with experience with this particular software.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this set of concrete examples how to use the different controls:
http://demos.shieldui.com/aspnetcore/

Also, there is no specific documentation for Shield UI's components for different technologies like .NET and Java, because those are wrappers around the JavaScript components, which are perfectly documented on their [documentation](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation).